# Converting Array length to Mega byte

Tags: c#

It might sound really really really stupid, but is there any way I can convert ArrayLength to Mega bytes.

```
    XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas readerQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
    readerQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
    binding.ReaderQuotas = readerQuotas;
```

I got this piece and I am not sure how to give it maximum size 50 Mega bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN, it looks like the [MaxArrayLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreaderquotas.maxarraylength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in bytes:

> Gets and sets the maximum allowed array length.
>
> **Property Value**
>   Type: System.Int32
>
> The maximum allowed array length. The default is 16384.
>
> This quota governs the maximum array length that is created and
>   returned by various API calls. It affects special array APIs as well
>   as byte arrays returned from ReadContentAsBase64(). This limit does
>   not affect the ReadContentAsBase64() override that takes an array to
>   be populated with data.

1 KB is 1024 bytes.  1 MB is 1024 KB.  So it sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
readerQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50 MB
```

Comment: can you firm if MaxArrayLength is taking bytes in please :(

Comment: @CustomizedName From the documentation it appears that the number is in bytes.